# SSRS and MDX causes VStudio to crash

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I am trying to generate a report using reporting services in visual studio 2005. the data source is in MDX DB and was created successfuly. When I save the query in the query builder window it closes and displays an alert : "the query cannot be read from the query window, please check for syntax errors"
and then VS crushes!

the query has no parameters and works on management studio without any problems.

I have installed all of my win updates, but sql server sp3 (that had a problem)
I also have service pack 2 for my framework

any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

try pasting from VS into notepad (or SSMS) and then copy from notepad (or SSMS) back into VS to make sure that there are not any "strange" characters (like smart quotes). It's vaugely possibly that SSMS is stripping these out when you paste into it.

Otherwise it may be an issue with your failed SP3 install.